# Winter Bash traduzido parcialmente?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, winterbash-2016

Na [página do Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) possui a opção de traduzir a descrição dos **Hats**.

Gostaria de saber apenas se existe algum fator para a descrição do "evento" não ser traduzida juntamente com a descrição dos chapéus.

A imagem abaixo ilustra melhor o que estou falando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a descrição de cada chapéu está em português. Porém, a descrição do evento não segue a mesma linha.

Comment: O esquema de tradução dos chapéus não levava em consideração o parágrafo que ia ter ali esse ano por conta do vídeo. To conversando com os devs pra ver o que pode ser feito.

Comment: @Gabe Entendo que são duas coisas diferentes e entendo a lógica. Apenas acho que se tem o botão de traduzir, poderia traduzir os demais itens. Mas, não quer dizer que isso atrapalhará a usabilidade e/ou o Winter Bash, é apenas uma "pontatinhda" de desconforto. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como eu disse [no comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5561/winter-bash-traduzido-parcialmente#comment21036_5561), esse ano nós usamos o mesmo esquema de frontend pra traduzir o texto dos chapéus que foi usado no ano passado. E ele não levava em consideração que esse ano teríamos esse texto a mais.

A versão traduzida deve ir ao ar em algum ponto do dia hoje.

Comment: Apenas para avisar que já vi no site e está traduzido. Parabenizo toda a equipe pela rapidez, tanto da resposta quando da implementação.

Comment: @Randrade Se você não tivesse avisado eu não teria visto

Comment: @LCarvalho que bom que ele avisou então 